JS regex doesn't match "À" character
This regular expression: /\b(?:A|AO|À|E|O)\b/gu is failing to catch the "À" word in this string: ENVIO AO AUTOR E À RÉ and I don't understand the reason.
Could someone clarify it and/or help me to fix it so that word is captured?
Please see test at Regex101

Looks like \b is the offender. For some reason the JS regex matcher doesn't consider that character to be "at a word boundary", even when it's directly next to a whitespace character. Other regex engines do!

@0stone0, thanks, that question does happen to be similar. But I couldn't find it because its title sort of contains the answer (which I wasn't aware of).

More astonishing yet, that question was asked in 2012 and we still face that problem.

Interesting to see that both JavaScript and Golang seem to have the same trouble and that it works fine in PHP, Python, .NET, Java and Rust. By the way, \w should ideally be replaced by \p{L} to match any word character in any language. To solve your problem, use /(?<=\P{L}|^)(?:A|AO|À|E|O)(?=\P{L}|$)/gu. In action here: https://regex101.com/r/hz2Zrw/1

@VBobCat Well you cannot just change what a word character is (what \w matches, where \b matches) without breaking the entire web

@Bergi Effectively, changing the behaviour of \w and \b could have some side effects. But this is also why they added the new u and v flags. An old regex not using these flags won't be affected by the change. Most all other languages did this change without breaking the entire web (PHP is probably one of the most used server-side language).

@VBobCat In addition to my solution above, I was just thinking about the fact that À can be written in two different ways: NFC or NFD. This means that À can be done either just with the code point number 192 or a with a sequence of two code points, the A followed by ', respectively code point number 65 and 768. So it might be good to run the .normalize('NFC') String method on your input, before searching for the À (code point 192).

@PatrickJanser: two comments regarding your pattern: - you can avoid the alternation in your lookarounds with a simple negation: (?<!\p{L}) and (?!\p{L}). - Even if proceed to a NFC normalization before, nothing proves that all combining characters are going to disappear (since many accented letters don't exist as a single code point in the UCS).

@CasimiretHippolyte: Thanks! Very good idea to use the negative lookarounds and make it even shorter and simplier. I'll not this one down :-) About the normalization, I'm sorry, but I lost you. I just tested "À".normalize("NFD").match(/À/u) and it returns null because it's the 2 code point version. But if you convert it back to NFC (single code point), then you get the match as "À".normalize("NFD").normalize("NFC").match(/À/u) returns the match like @VBobCat wants to.

I learned a lot of things from you guys! Thank you so much! I think what @CasimiretHippolyte means is that, differently from À, there are other characters for which there isn't a single code point representation. Although I don't have an example to give at the moment.
